# how to protect to delete previous value of class element

Tags: php, ajax, class, oop, laravel

I have controller class in laravel in  which i have a function create() and a variable attachment i am calling function  by ajax 
my class code is.

```
class AttachmentController extends Controller
{
    public  $_attachments;

    public function create()
    {

            $this->_attachments[]=  'test';

            var_dump($this->_attachments);



    }
```

problem is every time when i call it by ajax it return me "test" at 0 index of attachment array . but i want if i call create function 1st time it give me test on 0 index but when next time when i call it . it give me  "test" on both 0 and 1 index and so on .. 
how it is possible please help me

Comment: because `_attachments` is an array. And you are adding value to the variable everytime you call the function.

Comment: i am adding value in attachment variable that is an array .. but every it give me "test" on 0 index.. but i don't want it like this i want if call function one time it give me array(0=>'test') but when i call function second time it should give me output like this array(0=>'test',1=>'test') but it still giving me array(0=>'test')

Comment: I can't understand you. How do you want your output to be? Give me an example.

Comment: ok let me explain if i call create function first time it give me output 
[0=>'test']
but when second time when i call it . it still giving me same output but it should give me 
[0=>'test',1=>'test']

Comment: HTTP requests are not connected from one to the next. So if you are calling the `createAction` through a web browser multiple times, it will always act like you call it the first time. It sounds like you want to 'remember' the attachments, in which case you will need to store it somewhere (like a `session`, or a `database` or a `filesystem`).

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the values between requests you need to store them somewhere, an alternative is to use sessions, as the example below, for more information see https://laravel.com/docs/session

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AttachmentController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {   
        $request->session()->push('attachments', 'test');
        var_dump($request->session()->get('attachments'));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response above solution is not solving me problem in fact  i am upload attachment by using dropzone.js . when i upload single single file then its working fine but i upload multiple file but it still not working

Comment: So you want to upload one by one and save the name of the files already uploaded? Or you want to upload all the files at once?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$_attachments[] =  Session::get('test');
$_attachments[] = 'test';
Session::get('test', $_attachments);
dd(Session::get('test'));
```

let me know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Since HTTP driven applications are stateless, sessions provide a way
>   to store information about the user across requests.

```
class AttachmentController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        $attachments = Session::get('attachments', array());

        $attachments[] = 'test';

        Session::put($attachments);

        var_dump($this->_attachments);
    }
}
```

Further reading: [Laravel Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session)